# Finding and copying files in Terminal

Tags: command-line, find, copy

I have a .txt file (called list.txt) containing a list of filenames, including their paths.
Such as:

> /Users/Me/Downloads/0001.pdf
>   /Users/Me/Downloads/0010.pdf
>   /Users/Me/Downloads/0053.pdf
>   etc.

I want these copied to a folder on my desktop called "new-folder".
I use this script in Terminal to do it:

```
cp `cat /Users/Me/Desktop/list.txt` /Users/Me/Desktop/new-folder/
```

And this works spendidly!
But now I want to expand this functionality.
First of all, it doesn't work if the paths contain spaces, which is not very practical.
Second, I'm not always sure of the paths. I would like Terminal to search in a certain folder and its subfolders for the file called "0001.pdf".

My knewledge of Terminal is pretty much limited to this one script, just so you guys know.
I hope someone can help me, and many thanks in advance!

Comment: That does not look like Ubuntu.

Comment: You're right. I had found several leads towards my original script on this site, and I thought this was the right place for me to ask my question. I was wrong, please excuse me.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `xargs` to quote each line.

```
xargs -a list.txt -I% cp "%" destination/
```

Your second requirement isn't very practical but assuming list is just a list of filenames, something like this could work:

```
xargs -a list.txt -L1 -I% find -name "%" -exec cp {} destination/ \; -quit
```

It'll pass successive lines to `find` which will find the first file (in the current directory, recursive) with that name and copy it.

Comment: Alternatively one can use  `--arg-file` flag instead of redirection

Comment: This didn't work for me. Possibly because the xargs command is unfamiliar to me. I'm gonna read up more on it, use this as a lead to get further. Thank you so much for your input,

Comment: It was brought to my attention above that I have inadvertedly posted my question on the wrong site, as it has nothing to do with ubuntu. I appreciate the help, but I understand if this topic will be closed soon to keep this site clean. Thank you so much though!